# CMake - Export target such that it can be Imported into another project and support relocation

Tags: cmake

The below command will generate a my-targets-build-tree.cmake
However, it will have absolute paths for the IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE field for all targets.

```
export(
  EXPORT my-targets
  FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/share/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}/my-targets-build-tree.cmake"
)
```

This means that I can use the file to import targets into another project, but only if the libraries are not moved on disk. Meaning... things are not relocateable... i.e. you can't move the package anywhere randomly on another machine for instance.

Is there a way to make the generated cmake files support package relocation? For instance by having them consider an environment variable?

Comment: A command `export(EXPORT)` exports the **build tree** of the project. Since a build tree is not expected to be moved/copied, do not expect relocatable export for that case. You probably want to export **installation tree**, which could be done in relocatable manner. Installation tree is exported with `install(EXPORT)` command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`install(TARGETS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets) command to tell cmake how the files should be placed on the disk when installing them and use [`install(EXPORT)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#export) to create the configuration file instead of `export()`:

```
set(MYLB_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DESTINATION include/my_lib)

add_library(my_lib ...)

# need to provide location in installation dir and build dir separately here
target_include_directories(my_lib PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${MYLB_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DESTINATION}>)

install(TARGETS my_lib EXPORT my_lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib # static and import libs installed to lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib # .so installed to lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin # .dlls installed to bin 
    )

# install directory containing public headers to include/my_lib
install(DIRECTORY include DESTINATION ${MYLB_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DESTINATION}
    FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ GROUP_READ WORLD_READ
    DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE)

# create cmake config to lib/cmake/my_libConfig.cmake
install(EXPORT my_lib
    DESTINATION lib/cmake
    FILE my_libConfig.cmake)
```

This allows you to

1. Use the install target to write the files to a directory you specified via [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) or
2. Use cpack to create a package, assuming other info for the package for the package generator is set.